# How to extract data from a Editable Table Form with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have a table inside a form each row correspond to data that can be extract alone. usualy when i submit the form all row are send to the request post. So i add checkboxes to each row in order to select only the raw that supposed to be send and not the other like the picture bellow :

[image]

i have to find a solution but i don't know where to start i have to send the request in ajax 
i'm new at coding so if anyone have a lead that can help me resolve this issue  or how can i reform my question  i will appreciate

my code look like this :

```html
<form action="" method="post">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-inbox"></i></th>
                    <th scope="col">Consulant</th>
                    <th scope="col">cra</th>
                    <th scope="col">taux</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                    <td>The One</td>
                    <td><select name="Cras_status[]" id="">
                        <option value="">--Choississez le status--</option>
                        <option value="1">En cours</option>
                        <option value="">Validité</option>
                        <option value="">Refuser</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input name="taux" type="number"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                    <td>The Two</td>
                    <td><select name="Cras_status[]" id="">
                        <option value="">--Choississez le status--</option>
                        <option value="1">En cours</option>
                        <option value="2">Validité</option>
                        <option value="3">Refuser</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input type="number"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                    <td>The Three</td>
                    <td><select name="Cras_status[]" id="">
                        <option value="">--Choississez le status--</option>
                        <option value="1">En cours</option>
                        <option value="2">Validité</option>
                        <option value="3">Refuser</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input name type="number"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                    <td>The Four</td>
                    <td><select name="Cras_status[]" id="">
                        <option value="">--Choississez le status--</option>
                        <option value="1">En cours</option>
                        <option value="2">Validité</option>
                        <option value="3">Refuser</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input type="number"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                    <td>The Five</td>
                    <td><select name="" id="">
                        <option value="">--Choississez le status--</option>
                        <option value="1">En cours</option>
                        <option value="2">Validité</option>
                        <option value="3">Refuser</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input name="taux" type="number"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <div class="float-right">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
              </div>
              
             
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work for you within modern browsers.

```js
function submitFormAction(event, form) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var data = new FormData();
    for (var row of rows) {
        let checked = row.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked;
        let option = row.querySelector('select')
        let rate = row.querySelector('input[type="number"]');
        if (checked) {
            data.append(option.name, option.value);
            data.append(rate.name, rate.value);
        }
    }
    fetch("some/url", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            //Do some stuff
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            //Handle failure
        })
}

window.onload = ((event) => {
    const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    form.onsubmit = ((submitEvent) => submitFormAction(submitEvent, form));
})
```

Alternatively, if you want the request to be handled through a regular browser form submit, one approach would be to use javascript to copy the selected element values into a second hidden form and submit that one.

It would also be a good idea to add some ids to your important html elements. For example `<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">` would let you use `document.getElementById('#myForm');` and avoid the `[0]` collection access. This would also keep your code from breaking if you restructure your page or add more forms.

Comment: i did some modification to be able to retrieve the data as an array of object :

Answer (score 0):

I manage to retreive  the data in a array object :

```js
function submitFormAction(event, form) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
       var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
       var Test = [];
       var data = new FormData();
       for (var row of rows) {
           let checked = row.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked;
           let consultant = row.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
           let option = row.querySelector('select');
           let rate = row.querySelector('input[type="number"]');
           if(checked) {
               Test.push({
                   'consultant_name': consultant.value, 
                   'Type de cra' : option.value,
                   'Taux' : rate.value });           
           }
           
           
       }
       for (key in Test){
                    data.append('Consultant[]', JSON.stringify(Test[key]));
                }
                console.log(Test);
       var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       request.open("POST", "bottle.php", true);
       request.send(data);

        
   }
    window.onload = ((event) => {
        const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
        form.onsubmit = ((submitEvent) => submitFormAction(submitEvent, form));
    })
```

```html
 <div>
 <form action="" method="post">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-inbox"></i></th>
                    <th scope="col">Consulant</th>
                    <th scope="col">cra</th>
                    <th scope="col">taux</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                    <td><input name="Consulant[]" type="text" value="The One"></td>
                    <td><select name="Cras_status[]" id="">
                        <option value="">--Choississez le status--</option>
                        <option value="En_cours">En cours</option>
                        <option value="Valide">Validité</option>
                        <option value="Refuser">Refuser</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input name="taux[]" name="taux" type="number"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                    <td><input name="Consulant[]" type="text" value="The Two"></td>
                    <td><select name="Cras_status[]" id="">
                        <option value="">--Choississez le status--</option>
                        <option value="En_cours">En cours</option>
                        <option value="Valide">Validité</option>
                        <option value="Refuser">Refuser</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input name="taux[]" type="number"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                    <td><input name="Consulant[]" type="text" value="The Three"></td>
                    <td><select name="Cras_status[]" id="">
                        <option value="">--Choississez le status--</option>
                        <option value="En_cours">En cours</option>
                        <option value="Valide">Validité</option>
                        <option value="Refuser">Refuser</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input name="taux[]" type="number"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                    <td><input name="Consulant[]" type="text" value="The Four"></td>
                    <td><select name="Cras_status[]" id="">
                        <option value="">--Choississez le status--</option>
                        <option value="En_cours">En cours</option>
                        <option value="Valide">Validité</option>
                        <option value="Refuser">Refuser</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input name="taux[]" type="number"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                    <td><input name="Consulant[]" type="text" value="The five"></td>
                    <td><select name="" id="">
                        <option value="">--Choississez le status--</option>
                        <option value="En_cours">En cours</option>
                        <option value="Valide">Validé</option>
                        <option value="Refuser">Refuser</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input name="taux[]" type="number"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <div class="float-right">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
              </div>
              
             
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works. However, if you're parsing JSON on the server anyway, you don't need to use a FormData object. You can simply add your objects to `Test`, then add:

`request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");`

`request.send(JSON.stringify(Test))`